# How To Apply Security Patches

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to ask 1 simple question in SQL SERVER.....

How To Apply Security Patches in SQL SERVER 2000 and above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sql security patches (and also service packs) are usually downloaded from Microsoft as EXE files (usually 3 options for x86, x64, or IA64)

To apply these patches, you just run the EXE file directly on the server.

Note: the answer can be slightly different for the free versions of SQL Server 2000 (e.g. MSDE, Sql Express)

Comment: i need 1 more answer that if users are connected, then how to shutdown server safely..?

Comment: Depending on the patch (and version) you will find that some patches can be applied live.

Otherwise, either a "Net stop mssqlserver" or the TSQL command (SHUTDOWN) should be fine.